# Create sum of counts for duplicate values

Tags: r

I have the following participant dataset containing location information with derived binary variables of `invite` and `visit`.

```
id=c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
fsa=c("K3M", "L5N", "M3T", "N2P", "Q3L", "K3M", "M3T", "N2P")
invite=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
visit=c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
df=data.frame(id, fsa, invite, visit)
```

I want to create a sum of counts of the binary variables to see how many participants in a certain location have been invited/visited. Therefore, for all duplicate fsa, I want to  derive the sum of invites and visits, like this:

The unique identifiers doesn't matter here -- I just want a tally

```
fsa=c("K3M",  "L5N", "M3T", "N2P", "Q3L")
invite=c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
visit=c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0)
df.tomake=data.frame(fsa, invite, visit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate here

```
aggregate(cbind(invite,visit)~fsa, df, sum)
```

This will take the sum of invite and visit for each value of fsa.

Comment: Can this be done if there were more than 2 variables to get the sum for?

Comment: After forcing all the variables to be numeric and running the code you suggested, I get this error message:Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) :
  no rows to aggregate

Comment: Sounds like a typo? Or you passed the wrong data.frame name in the command?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to specify column names and you want a fast aggregation, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = fsa, .SDcols=-c("id")]

##    fsa invite visit
## 1: K3M      2     2
## 2: L5N      1     0
## 3: M3T      1     0
## 4: N2P      1     1
## 5: Q3L      1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   group_by(fsa) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(sum), -1)
 #  Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

 #  fsa invite visit
 #1 K3M      2     2
 #2 L5N      1     0
 #3 M3T      1     0
 #4 N2P      1     1
 #5 Q3L      1     0
```